# Why instance of superclass can be put into array of subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

Let's assume we have 2 classes:

```
class X { }

class Y extends X { }
```

Create an array in main function:

```
Y[] yArr = new Y[3] // created Y's class objects array

X[] xArr = yArr;

xArr[0]= new X() // VALID. WHY?
```

How can it be?? Because `xArr` refers to `Y[]` object and for my understanding it cannot create an X object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Java compiler allows this because in Java arrays are covariant.  I.e., one can say:

```
Superclass[] arr = new Subclass[3];
```

This allows code such as your `xArr[0]= new X();` to compile.  However, the JVM will catch this error at runtime and throw an `ArrayStoreException`.  It knows at runtime that it's really a `Y[3]` and thus can't store an `X`.

The [JLS, Section 4.10.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3), establishes the covariance of array types:

> The following rules define the direct supertype relation among array
>   types:
>
> - If S and T are both reference types, then S[] >1 T[] iff S >1 T.
> - Object >1 Object[]
> - Cloneable >1 Object[]
> - java.io.Serializable >1 Object[]
> - If P is a primitive type, then:
>
>   - Object >1 P[]
>   - Cloneable >1 P[]
>   - java.io.Serializable >1 P[]

This is in contrast to generics, which not covariant -- they are invariant.  I.e.

```
ArrayList<Superclass> list = new ArrayList<Subclass>();  // doesn't compile.
```